Duplicate text on console with SSH
When I SSH into my kali machine from Fedora and try to run a command and press TAB to autocomplete it as below...

Then the moment I press TAB it does this:

Notice that first sudo? It somehow just pops up and is nothing but pixels on the screen and isn't part of command if I hit enter. So if I backspace completely and hit enter, sudo still remains on-screen but there's no help box of sudo command if it was actually run on pressing enter.

I could only test this by doing the same in actual VM and there, there is no such issue. Any idea what is happening here?
And if it matters, I had to generate and change UUIDS for this VM and add MOK keys since I blatantly copied VM folder when changing distros instead of cloning it. And in my previous Ubuntu host OS, this issue wasn't happening.
Variables:

$TERM is xterm-256color in both
Locale is set to UTF-8 on both

$PS1 in VM:
┌──(kali㉿kali-pc)-[~]
└─$ echo "$PS1"  
%F{%(#.blue.green)}┌──${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)─}${VIRTUAL_ENV:+($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV))─}(%B%F{%(#.red.blue)}%n㉿%m%b%F{%(#.blue.green)})-[%B%F{reset}%(6~.%-1~/…/%4~.%5~)%b%F{%(#.blue.green)}]
└─%B%(#.%F{red}#.%F{blue}$)%b%F{reset}

Edit: further troubleshooting to find "when" this happens and "what" it does

Found on autocompletion (when there are more than 1 possible options!), with TAB and not right-arrow to complete from last used suggestion.
Also happens every time I press ctrl+D (from 1 character to complete command typed on console)
Messes up exactly first 4 character space every time from $ prompt as seen below


I typed network before pressing TAB and again, only first 4 were affected

Using small cd command and pressed TAB and again the first 4 characters got messed up.
Edit 2: Simply setting PS1='$ ' 'solves' it, but that doesn't explain what is happening here.

Do you have a particular use case for Kali Linux. It is designed for penetration and security testing and not for general use. It was also designed for experts who have an advanced understanding of Linux. This isn't meant to be condescending but if this is giving you trouble, then Kali isn't for you.

@NasirRiley yes, I am using these systems and OSes for quite some time now.

@NasirRiley That fact is likely unrelated to the issue at hand. The issue is likely able to be solved regardless of the fact that Kali Linux happens to be involved.

@1zverg What is the value of the TERM variable (on Fedora, and in Kali Linux), and does changing it to something reasonable, like xterm make any difference with regards to your current issue?

@Kusalananda both TERM are xterm-256color and changing to xterm doesn't help. And if it did, I don't want to lose my beautiful colors :')

I wonder if it's the prompt $PS1 incorrectly set up? Please add the output of echo "$PS1" on the destination system to your question. As text, not a screenshot

@ChrisDavies provided in the original post. I assumed host's PS1 might not be necessary.

OK. I can't reproduce this, so I don't think it's the prompt. Possibly a conflict between whatever terminal emulator you're using and the definition xterm-256color (as suggested previously by others)

I added some extra things I could troubleshoot without taking apart my system. @ChrisDavies

If you change the prompt so that the second line contains other than four characters does the offset change to match the new character count?

Two thoughts. (1) The "-" characters are actually three-byte symbols and something is miscounting them as 3 characters each instead of one, (2) you've a UTF8 / locale / character set mismatch

@ChrisDavies simply setting PS1='$ ' solves everything :/ And yes! Kali has all locale as POSIX when SSHing (UTF-8 through GUI) but Fedora has as UTF-8. Is this the issue?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"Kali has all locale as POSIX" - I suspect so, yes

@ChrisDavies apparently, even after forwarding host locales, the issue still persists.

The reason for the problem was that my Kali system was running with a POSIX locale where every character fits in a single byte. The graphics characters in the prompt were all UTF-8 multibyte characters, such that the prompt ended up being four bytes longer than displayed characters. As a result, each time the new cursor position was calculated it was four characters away from its expected position.
Rebuilding locales and choosing a UTF-8 locale solved the issue:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

